# how to use jquery-backstretch in jsp

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jsp, spring-mvc, jquery-backstretch

found this jquery plugin on available here http://www.jquery-backstretch.com/,
however i would like to make use of it in my jsp page when i call the $.backstretch() method to set background image, and havent been able to...
below is my code

```
<script>
    document.ready(function(){
       $.backstretch("/resources/imgs/WP_20170327_11_46_24_Pro.jpg");
    });
</script>
```

also set the resources appropriately as follows:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/WEB-INF/resources/" />
```

Comment: try with $.backstretch("<c:url value="/resources/imgs/image.jpg"></c:url>"); and remove document.ready function.

Comment: thanks but still not functioning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried it with jquery-backstretch v2.0.4 and it works but v2.1.5 not work.

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-backstretch/2.0.4/jquery.backstretch.min.js"></script>

$.backstretch("<c:url value="/resources/imgs/arkaplan.jpg"></c:url>");
```

Or

```
$.backstretch("${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/imgs/arkaplan.jpg");
```